# Collections.sort(<StringDate>, new Comparator) is not comparing the dates properly

Tags: java, sorting, date, jodatime

I have a List of dates in dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm format stored as a string When I try to sort these dates I get all the values sorted properly except for the 00 hours and 12 hours values

The array comes in a 15 minute interval so after sorting i get something like

```
00:15, 12:15, 00:30, 12:30, 00:45, 12:45, 1:00, 1:15, 1:30....
```

Below is the code for the sorting

```
Collections.sort(dates, new Comparator<String>() {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                try {
                    return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me out here how do i go ahead with this

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP is parsing the strings into `Date` objects before comparing.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen True, look at the `Comparator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SimpleDateFormat`, use `HH` for hours instead of `hh`:

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that... that was something i dint know